# How to configure a write only layer on Geoserver?

Tags: security, ldap, authorization, layer, geoserver

This is probably a wrong way of doing it, but I was exploring this option only because I do not know how to implement the right solution.

We have a layer to which features are added using WFS-T. We have configured Geoserver to authenticate and authorize via LDAP.

While querying for features, we would like Geoserver to return features based on the user/role.

Since I do not know how to set feature based security (row level security), my thought was to see if we can make the layer write only and not allow any read operation.

The read will be done through a SQL Parametric View layer will add a WHERE cause to filter by an unique value.

For doing that, I have this setting in layers.properties workspace.layer.w=ROLE_USER workspace.layer.r=SUPERUSER

However this doesn’t seem to work and I am not able to do any WFS-T on the layer although this user has the correct role. Reading s

What would be the right strategy to implement this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try it myself, but if you are using one of the latest version of geoserver you should be able to use [geofence plugin from geosolutions](https://github.com/geosolutions-it/geofence/wiki/Main-concepts).

AFAIK you can configure cql filters on the layer to limit the set of rows returned to the user based on the user autorization.